# Im building a face detector but Im having a challenge resizing the captured frame to match that of the model hence the error below

Tags: python, opencv, deep-learning, mobilenet

Here is the code generating the error

This is the structure of my model's base. I am import MobileNetV2 but I'm leaving out the top layers.

```
baseModel = MobileNetV2(weights="imagenet", include_top=False, input_tensor=Input(shape=(224, 224, 3)))
```

Then I am now creating a face detector with opencv. The face detector captures the face and the model predicts whether the face is wearing  a face mask or not.

This line below is generating the error because I'm not resizing the captured image frame into the appropriate size of the model input.

```
for (x,y,w,h) in faces:
    
        face_img = grayscale_img[y:y+w,x:x+w]
        resized_img = cv2.resize(face_img,(56,56))
        normalized_img = resized_img/255.0
        reshaped_img = np.reshape(normalized_img,(224, 224, 3))
        result=model.predict(reshaped_img)
```

The error generated is below

ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 3136 into shape (224,224,3)

What's the right way to reshape this img? Thank you

Comment: you are reshaping `56x56` array into `224x224x3` array! you might want to resize it to the proper shape `224x224x3`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

that error looks like the array may be only 1D, regardless there isn't enough pixels to make up a 224x224x3 image.

if the face image is grayscale then you wont be able to reshape it to 3 channels, you'll have to either copy it to the other 3 channels:

```
grayscale_img = grayscale_img[y:y+w,x:x+w]
face_img = np.stack([grayscale_img,grayscale_img,grayscale_img], axis= -1)## three channels
```

or convert the top of you model to a single channel, possibly (i am not certain) by using the following when you create the model:

```
input_tensor=Input(shape=(224, 224, 1)
```

you'd then resize the image width and height using either opencv or np:

```
resized_img = cv2.resize(face_img, (224,224)) ## opencv
```

MobileNetv2 needs to be normalised between (-1,1) therefore:

```
normalized_img = resized_img/128 -1
```

you might want to look into:

https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/slim/nets/mobilenet/mobilenet_example.ipynb

if your grayscale img is very small you may want to try to adjust the model to accept smaller images rather than enlarging them